# Using a value stored in a vector to delete rows in a dataframe

Tags: r, rows, delete-row, refer

So,
I have a high number of dataframes that I need to delete the top and bottom 5% from and afterwards calculate descriptives from the Sums of rows.

I am trying to put as many steps as possible into on command in order to forgo as much typework as possible.

Now I think I am almost there (though my solution my not be as pretty).
I set the code up in a way that it calculates me the number of rows that is roughly equal to 5% of the total number of rows and stores it in a vector.

I then try to refer to the vector when using a command to delete the rows in the dataframe.

However, the command does not delete a number of rows equal to the stored value but as it seems only equal to the number of rows in the vector which is of course only 1.
e.g.:TEST <- TEST[-c(test), ]  (TEST is the dataframe and test is the vector with the calculated number of rows)

Is there a way to refer to the value within test when telling R how many rows it should delete of the top of the dataframe?  (To get the top 5% afterwards I would simply resort descending and repeat step 1)

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Try `TEST[-seq(test), ]`

Comment: YES! Thank you!

As a fair beginner learning things bit by bit through doing raher than straigh courses, what does seq refer to?  Sequence?

Comment: yes. Type seq(5) in the console and you'll see